# How does a decimal get converted into dotted decimal

Tags: math, numbers, data-conversion, number-systems

Is the way to convert the decimal to hexadecimal and then to doted decimal.And does it always have to be 10 digit decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to binary and then to dotted decimal. The number must be within 223.255.255.255 and not necessarily of just 10 digits.